# Joomla Plugin to fire onUserLogin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

All, I have a simple plugin which does fire on login. I have the same plugin working in 2.5 but in my joomla 3.5 I cannot get it work get the username. This does work on Joomla 2.5

Here it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
class PlgUserAddInfo extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array())
    {
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $mysignum = $user->username;
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('mysignum', $mysignum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use the onUserAfterLogin method instead: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterLogin

Answer (score 2):

In joomla 2.5 function onUserLogin() is used for your purpose. But in our joomla version 3.5 we use function onUserAfterLogin() is using.

You will also follow the link 
https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterLogin 
for more reference