# User Plugin onUserAfterLogin

Tags: plugin, user

I am writing a custom user plugin to write the session id and user id on a txtfile(This will be in turn used for some of my perl systems) after the user logins on Joomla. So far i have managed to create xml file and the main php file.

```
defined('_JEXEC');
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

echo "hello"; //this works as when I login I can see the message on top of the message which makes me believe that the user plugin is installed correctly

// Whatever I try to print in the class, it seems to ignore.
class PlgUserperllogin extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAfterLogin($options)
    {
          $user = JFactory::getUser();
          $user_id = $user->get('username');
          $usertype = $user->get('usertype');
          $session = JFactory::getSession();
          $sessionid = $session->getId();
          //write to txt file
          //set cookie for the same
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is missing. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: is this joomla 3 or 2.5?
you might find the discussion here helpful also.
http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16754/joomla-plugin-to-fire-onuserlogin

Comment: Its Joomla 3 . I have tried  it. Its just that the action doesn't seem to fire the event. If i print  say hello , before the class begins it prints fine on joomla after login, but doesn't seem to recognize anything in the class. I would really appreciate any help this.

Comment: there could be a few things wrong.

1. is your plugin in the plugins/user/yourpluginname folder?
2. do you open your class like: class PlgUserYourpluginname extends JPlugin
3. put a die() function in your code incase you're just being redirected before seeing any ouput.
4. slightly unrelated, you dont need to get the user object again, it's in the $options.

Comment: Yes, I have follwed the structure after reading the documentation and yet i do not undesratnd what i am missing. It just doesn't seem to fire the event not sure why. I will try to use the options array and get the user id and things.

Comment: After trying various events just to see which event works. onUserLogout works , i am not sure why onUserAfterLogin doesn't work. I am really struggling to understand, why one event on the same class would work and other won't .

Comment: Could you give the exact path of the plugin please? For example: `plugins\user\profile\profile.php`

Answer (score 2):

The class name is case sensitive with Joomla, so make sure your plugin name is correct. For example, if the path of the plugin is:

> plugins/user/something/something.php

then you would use:

```
class PlgUserSomething extends JPlugin
```

You should also be aware that `usertype` is deprecated. If you wish to get the group[s] of a user, have a look at another answer I wrote:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407692/1362108

---

So for the actual plugin code, try using the following:

#### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.6" type="plugin" group="user" method="upgrade">
    <name>Something</name>
    <author>My Name</author>
    <creationDate>27-01-2017</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2017</copyright> 
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html</license> 
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>Something</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="something">something.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

#### PHP:

```
defined('_JEXEC');

class PlgUserSomething extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAfterLogin($options)
    {
          // User data
          $user_id = $options['user']->id;
          $groups  = $options['user']->groups;

          $allGroups = '';
          foreach($groups as $group)
          {
              $allGroups .= 'Group Id = ' . $group . ' ';
          }

          // Session data
          $session = JFactory::getSession();
          $sessionid = $session->getId();

          JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('The user ID is: ' . $user_id);
          JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('The session ID is: ' . $sessionid);

          // $allGroups is a string containing all the groups
          // Write to txt file
          // Set cookie for the same
    }
}
```

Of course changing `PlgUserSomething` to the correct value for you.

Comment: I will keep in mind about the usertype  and use groups instead. I have again double checked my class name to make sure, i am doing the right thing. Like mentioned, i tried to use OnUserLogout event and it works so i am not sure what is going wrong . It just doesn't fire it even if i put die to check whether there is a problem with my event.

Comment: @TejuDesai - What exact version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.6.4.

Comment: I would really appreciate any help on this....

Comment: I'll try replicating the plugin at work today and get back to you

Comment: You are a star. I will keep trying my best until then....

Comment: @TejuDesai - I've updated the code for the replica plugin I made. The plugin event `onUserAfterLogin` **does** work, so perhaps the rest of your code is what isn't working. If you copy and paste my PHP code above, then try to login, you'll see a green box appear with the user and session ID's.

Comment: Ok, I have tried again by creating everything again , but unfortunately its same thing. It doesn't display the message and redirects to the user profile page. Below is what i did, posting again so can pin point if anything missing.Create User plugin folder within plugins/user/  called test

Comment: `code`                                                                                               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.6" type="plugin" group="user" method="upgrade">
    <name>Test</name>
    <author>Teju Desai</author>
    <creationDate>27-01-2017</creationDate>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>test plugin to get the details</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="test">test.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>                                                                                    `code`

Comment: `code` defined('_JEXEC');
class PlgUsertest extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAfterLogin($options)
    {
          // User data
          $user_id = $options['user']->id;
          $groups  = $options['user']->groups;

          $allGroups = '';
          foreach($groups as $group)
          {
              $allGroups .= 'Group Id = ' . $group . ' ';
          }
          // Session data
             JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('The user ID is: ' . $user_id);
              }
}
?>
`code`

Comment: do i have to take care of ordering of plugins etc. As this just simply doesn't fire at all.

Comment: Ok give me 10 minutes and I'll use the code you've provided

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://imgur.com/a/qcJ1R You have enabled the plugin right?

Comment: Yes, i have enabled the right plugin. Mine redirects to the profile page and displays nothing. I am not sure what else  to look for.

Comment: I've just tested redirecting to the profile page and it still works fine for me. Are you doing a manual redirect or using the login module to set the redirection?

Comment: Its the Login module redirection by default not the manual . Is there any way i can debug to see what it is doing. Could it be something in the core files.

Comment: Trty adding `var_dump('true'); exit;` inside, but at the top of of your `onUserAfterLogin` function, then try loggin in and see if it dumps the value.

Comment: Its just a blank page .

Comment: Hmm ok in your Global Configuration, set error reporting to "development" and try again

Comment: Still the same blank screen

Comment: Hmm, in which case I'm lost. If the server cannot print `true` when using `var_dump('true'); exit;` then something is wrong. Not sure what version of PHP you're using but perhaps it needs updating, else try contacting your hosting provider

Comment: If I try and print outside the class, it prints true but not within the function onUserAfterLogin

Comment: Sorry, probably my fault. If i try to print this way.  public function onUserAfterLogin($options)
    {

        var_dump('true');
        exit;}  It still redirects to login page but doesn't print anything at all .

Comment: I am using latest php version and we host our own website so debugging becomes a little easy

Comment: @Lodder- Would it be possible for you to provide me os phpversion and joomla version . So i can create same sort of/ development environment and test the code.

Comment: Joomla 3.6.5 and PHP 7.0.10. Also tested on PHP 5.6.25

Comment: @LodderHello, i have just been downloading the new joomla installation and the version availaible for donwload is 3.6.4 no 3.6.5?

Comment: https://downloads.joomla.org/

Comment: Yes, you were right. I have created a development environment and the code works just fine. So, not sure what it is that's blocking on 3.6.4. Either some external plugin may be. I am going to install one by one the external plugins and see which one gives error message.

Comment: Does it work on a fresh installation of J3.6.4? https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/3.6.4

Comment: i haven't tried yet but will try soon.